# .htaccess rewrite subdomain with wild card for any subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have many multiple subdomains and would like an example how my .htaccess would look like using a wild card so I can rewrite any http://*.example.com to either goto the root or goto a folder.

This is what I have tried but it does not seem to work.  I have activated Rewrites in apache2.

```
Options +Includes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subdomain/).*)$ example.com $1 [L,NC]

AddType application/x-httpd-cgi .cgi .pl
AddType text/html .htm
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .sht .html .htm
```

I have all my subdomains in my apache2 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/httpd-vhosts-user.conf.

During my research I have tried many variants but cannot seem to get the syntax.

Like I mentioned, I have many multiple subdomains and have researched on line but with no luck.

**System set up:** I am using ubuntu server 18.04.5, running on a Qnap TS-453D,64-bit x86, Intel® Celeron® J4125 quad-core 2.0 GHz processor, 8GB Mem. Using VirtualizationStation 3 VMs, 6TB Disk Space Raid 5.

The above coding is the closest I think I could find . I am new to mod rewrites and their syntax meanings. .htaccess seems like such a powerful tool.  I would like an example of what the code should look like for my needs So, I can better research their meanings and uses.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your .htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Start yourself. Implement what you think you need. Then test it. Check the results. Adjust it to your needs. _Then_ , if you encounter issues you cannot solve yourself, _then_ is the time to come here and ask for help with the specific rules you yourself implemented.

Comment: What are you trying to match with `^((?!subdomain/).*)$`? Are you aware that RewriteRule only matches against the _path_ component of the URL?

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a wildcard so I can rewrite any http://*.example.com and then to retain and display the http://subdomain.example.com the the user typed in the browser.  I have tried many example found online. But I get BAD REQUEST error. I really don't understand the rewrite so every example I find that seems close to my needs I cut and past my domain in code and try it. What I need is  an actual example I might try.

Comment: I fail to understand this. You say you tried a number of examples, failed to succeed and now you ask for another example? Why should that one succeed now? A "Bad request" has nothing to do with rewriting. And also nothing with the syntax of entries in a configuration file as you suspect in the question. So the question is why your http server receives a "bad request". Please take a look into your http server's error log file to see what it actually says...

Comment: In general, if you want to learn about the rewriting module of the apache http server and about syntax and options in configuration files (".htaccess"), then I recommend that you use the documentation of those tools. In my experience that is more valuable then looking for examples somewhere on the web and trying to learn formal details from those.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are definitely correct.  I have read the documents a few times.   I am a 74 yr old who has a few learning disabilities that require me to actually see working examples that I can compare to the documentation in order to understand it.  I have also Googled for a few examples.  However, I have had a hard time finding any examples that fit my situation.  I would think it would be a very popular question for a "geek newbie" trying to build their own multiple domain web server.